# Netbeans Java Debugger crashing with Out of Memory Errors

Tags: java, tomcat, jsf, netbeans, permgen

Recently, while working on a JSF web app, using Netbeans 6.8, I am constantly getting PermGen: Out Of Memory Errors. I have also noticed that this is not related to hot swapping the code, as some people suggested on the forums; I generally restart my local web server, Tomcat 6.0, whenever I redeploy the code. This used to happen to me once in awhile, but as of late, it was been occurring constantly. I usually can't go more than two minutes before it crashes.

The important observation I've made about this problem, is that it only seems to happen when running the debugger. If I launch the server, regularly, it will run indefinitely. As soon as I run in debug mode, this problem occurs.

I've tried all the tips I've found so far of increasing the JAVA_OPT memory settings for Java in Tomcat; I've tried increasing the available memory for Netbeans in netbeans.conf. Still no luck. If you want to see the specific configuration changes I've made, I can post that as well.

I've also read that this can be a result of memory leaks in Java. I've tried running Netbean's profiler, but it would generally crash as well before I could do anything really useful. Additionally, when it did run, all the object allocations with ridiculous generations were things in java libraries, or primitives -- char[]s were the biggest memory hog of the app, for example, with the largest generations.

I would really like to know if anyone has had a similar problem before, and if so, how they solved it. This is starting to seriously impede my ability to do my work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does netbeans.conf show **-J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=200m** ?

Comment: I had this set previously to the same value, 1024m. I changed to your suggestion, setting it to 256, and 512 respectively. Now, it crashes differently. Whereas it used to blow up right away with PermGen error, now it usually just hangs, and sometimes I get an actual error, and other times, it just hangs up indefinitely.

Comment: You would need a heap dump first to identify the leaking objects and the ones keeping them alive. Once you know this you can either fix the problem right away (if it is simple enough and you are familiar with the code where the culprit lies) or use the profiler to pinpoint the places of the allocation of the leaking instances.

You can use jmap or visualvm (jvisualvm) to obtain the heap dump. For analysis you can use visualvm, too, but of course you can choose whatever tool you like - eg. MAT if you want to stick to free tools.

Answer (score 2):

add this entry in catlina.sh(or bat), it worked for me

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
    -server -Xms1536m -Xmx1536m
    -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=512m -XX:PermSize=512m 
    -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC
```

Comment: Thank you, i messed around with these settings in Netbeans while debugging a tomcat app until your question just made it all click.  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something I have found useful to track down memory leaks without running a profiler or a debugger is to use the "jmap -histo " command (comes with the jdk). Save the output of this program to a file.  Run this every few minutes while your application is running.  Collect up the outputs and look for objects that are always increasing in number and size.  I even wrote a quick app to graph selected objects over time to really highlight run away objects just to make it easier to see where leaks might be occurring.